# how to find out the likelihood of a model given data

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood

If i have a non-stochastic model that predicts the following dataset:

> [.2, .2]

and the actual dataset found empirically (averaged over participants) is

> [.3, .3]

How would I determine the likelihood of the model?

> p(Data|Model)

What if the data was:

> [.2, .2]

Would the likelihood be 1.0? What is the procedure for calculating model likelihood?

Comment: Please explain how the concept of likelihood would apply to your "non-stochastic" model.  Where exactly do you propose to introduce probabilities into the analysis?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assess the likelihood of a non-stochastic model. Another goodness-of-fit metric must be used to evaluate the model (e.g. RMSE, r^2)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is that you have 2 dimensional Binomial distribution both with means of 0.2 and you observe 0.3 in both of them.

If you assume they are independent, this is a standard problem and everything you need to know is here. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

In short, you also need to know the number of data points so the problem as stated is not yet solvable.